# Nested class in inner class

Tags: kotlin, inner-classes

Is there a way to define a nested class in an inner class? I thought nested classes were just a namespacing thing with no runtime consequence, so I don't understand why the below shouldn't typecheck:

```
class Outer {
    inner class Inner {
        class Nested {
    }
}
```

This gives me a "Class is not allowed here" error on the `class Nested` line.

Of course, I could just move the definition of `Nested` next to `Inner` and everything would work; but in my real use case, `Nested` is only relevant to the implementation of `Inner`, so I'd like to keep it inside.

Comment: In Java, an inner class is not allowed to declare static members. Kotlin uses the same principle. If it didn't, interoperability with Java would be much more messy only to benefit a fringe concern.

Answer (score 3):

So will this work?  Now Nested can access Inner and Outer.  Leaving out the nested inner is not permitted for various 'closure-ish' related issues.

```
class Outer {
    inner class Inner {
        inner class Nested {
    }
}
```

Data classes

```
data class Outer2(var foo: Int) {
    data class Inner(var foo: Int) {
        data class Nested(var foo: Int) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I'd like `Nested` to be a data class?

Comment: you can't use inner and data together.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that what if only `Nested` should be a data class? In that case, it can't be turned into an inner class of `Inner`, since data classes can't be inner classes.

Comment: Unfortunately the data classes are special and can't hold references to a parent.

Comment: Yes, which wouldn't be an issue if it was nested, not inner. Hence my original question.